# What character is this drawing of in Pop's Barbershop?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, luke-cage-2016

In season 2 of *Luke Cage*, you can see a children's drawing on the wall of Pop's Barbershop.

[image: Picture on wall of pop's barbershop]

Given that the Defenders series is chock full of easter eggs, I figured this random drawing must be intentional.

So, who or what is this a drawing of?

See below for an enhanced and cropped version of the drawing.

[image: Zoomed version of the drawing]

Comment: Do you happen to know the episode number? I'm going to look into this.

Comment: It’s Captain Deadpool. 

Comment: I'm so tempted to say it's Rom the SpaceKnight, just to make all the fans' hearts quicken...

Comment: (Rom doesn't have that level of asymmetry, even taking into account that this appears to be a child's drawing.)

Comment: @Gothamite24 This screenshot is from Season 2 Episode 4. It very well be in other episodes too or even in the first season.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Jay from LEGO Ninjago

Of all things this could have been, it appears to be the character *Jay* from the Ninjago TV series and toy LEGO line. From this photo posted on the [r/lego subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/lego/comments/55fbkp/ninjago_easter_egg_in_luke_cage/) it seems pretty obvious.

[image: Jay from LEGO Ninjago]

Added to that, the completely round, open circle hands and bent arms heavily suggests a LEGO figure. Furthermore, Jay is referred to as the ["Ninja of Lightning"](http://ninjago.wikia.com/wiki/Jay:_Ninja_of_Lightning) and has lightning based powers, which are present in the drawing.

Comment: I wasn't expecting this to be the answer in the slightest and was honestly hoping it was some deeper hint. Nope! The real question is how did this end up  here?